# How to retrieve color from a polygon in ArcObjects?

Tags: arcobjects

I tried the following code the get the polygon color, but it returns the same color (0, 0, 255) for all polygons. How can I get the color of a polygon with ArcObjects?

```cs
        // Get polygon.
        IGeometry geometry = feature.Shape;
        IPolygon4 polygon = (IPolygon4)geometry;

        // Get color.
        IElement element = new PolygonElementClass();
        element.Geometry = feature.Shape;

        IFillShapeElement fillElement = element as IFillShapeElement;
        IFillSymbol fillSymbol = fillElement.Symbol;
        IRgbColor color = fillSymbol.Color as IRgbColor;

        MessageBox.Show(color.Red.ToString() + " " + color.Green.ToString() + " " + color.Blue.ToString());
```

I also tried to retrieve an element from IGraphicsContainer as:

```cs
            IEnvelope2 envelope = polygon.Envelope as IEnvelope2;

            IGraphicsContainer graphicsContainer = map as IGraphicsContainer;

            IEnumElement enumElement = graphicsContainer.LocateElementsByEnvelope(envelope);

            enumElement.Reset();
            IElement element = enumElement.Next();
```

But the obtained enumElement is null. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I made it using IFeatureRenderer as:

```cs
            IGeoFeatureLayer geoGeatureLayer = featureLayer as IGeoFeatureLayer;
            IFeatureRenderer featureRenderer = geoGeatureLayer.Renderer;
            ISymbol symbol = featureRenderer.SymbolByFeature[feature];

            IFillSymbol fillSymbol = symbol as IFillSymbol;

            IColor color = fillSymbol.Color;

            IRgbColor rgbColor = new RgbColor();
            rgbColor.RGB = color.RGB;

            MessageBox.Show(rgbColor.Red.ToString() + " " + rgbColor.Green.ToString() + " " + rgbColor.Blue.ToString());
```